# Integer values of $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are the possible integer values of
$$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}$$
where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers?

My suspicion is the the only integer values are $3$ and $5$, the former achievable whenever $(x,y,z)=k(1,1,1)$, and the latter achievable when $(x,y,z)=k(1,2,4)$. This suspicion is only based on playing around with the numbers for a while. I tried multiplying out the factors and using divisibility arguments, but nothing came of it.

This question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848612/cannot-be-the-value-of-the-expression) one, so I'm particular interested if the given sum is ever equal to $4$.

EDIT: My suspicion has turned out to be quite wrong. Please see several examples of other solutions in the comments and answers.

Comment: In other words, when is $x^2z+y^2x+z^2y$ a multiple of $xyz$?

Comment: $2,36,81$ yields $41$.

Comment: @JackM right, although I'm more interested in the actual number $\dfrac{x^2z+y^2x+z^2y}{xyz}$

Comment: this could get complicated if it's anything like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402537/

Comment: @barakmanos nice find!

Comment: @mercio Oh dear, it does indeed appear similar.

Comment: $3,126,196$ yields $66$... $4,9,162$ yields $41$... $4,72,162$ yields $41$... $12,63,98$ yields $9$... $18,28,147$ yields $9$... $24,126,196$ yields $9$... And the list goes on...

Comment: It seems to be that if any two are equal, then the third must be as well (to be an integer)

Comment: $2,12,9$ yields $6$... $3,18,4$ yields $6$... $4,3,18$ yields $6$...

Comment: This is apparently one of those questions where a tiny bit of computer programming goes a long way. Your profile says you''re an undergraduate mathematics student, so let me make a pitch for you to learn some simple programming in some easy language like Python. It takes less than five minutes to write a program to exhaustively search all triples with $x,y,z\le 1,000$, and only a few minutes to run it and produce many examples, including barak manos's $(2,36,81)$.

Comment: @MJD: LOL, you got it right on each of the following statements: 1. I used Python. 2. It took me less than 5 minutes to write it down. 3. I used an exhaustive search for $x,y,z\leq1000$ (up until $800$ for each argument, to be more accurate)... Nice catch :)

Comment: @MJD This is true, I probably should have written a simple program, but when I first asked the question I was unaware of the difficulty - I thought I was probably missing a nice little algebraic argument for just a few solutions (especially as the motivating question didn't look like it was supposed to be difficult).

Comment: Although this shows there are more than 3 and 5 as possible solutions, if 4 is not possible, we can not show that via exhaustion (e.g. our program).  However if 4 is possible, this may be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Describing all values of $m$ such that the corresponding solution $(x,y,z)$ exists is an open problem. For the reference (quite old though), see the book of Serpinskii, Remark after solution of problem 155. The book is available here: [http://www.isinj.com/aime/250%20Problems%20in%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Sierpinski%20(1970).pdf](http://www.isinj.com/aime/250%20Problems%20in%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Sierpinski%20%281970%29.pdf)

However, something is known. For example, the equation $$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}=m$$ has no solution in positive integers $(x,y,z)$ for $m=4n^2$, where $n∈Z$ and $3$ does not divide $n$. On the other hand, if $m=k^2+5$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ then our equation has a solution.

The key idea to construct it is to note that is $(a,b,c)$ is a solution of 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=mabc,$$
then one can take $x=a^2b, y=b^2c, z=c^2a,$ to produce solution for the given equation. Now, for $m=k^2+5,$ one can easily take $a=2,b=k^2-k+1$ and $c=k^2+k+1.$

Therefore, your special question for $m=4$ is solved. For the reference, A.V. Bondarenko.

Investigation of a class of Diophantine equations. (Russian. English, Ukrainian summary) Ukraïn. Mat. Zh. 52 (2000), no. 6, 831--836;

Answer (score 6):

One of methods:
$p=\dfrac{x}{y}$, $q=\dfrac{y}{z}$, $r=\dfrac{z}{x}=\dfrac{1}{pq}$.

(one of them must be $\le 1$).

$$
p+q+\dfrac{1}{pq}=n,
$$

$$
p^2q+pq^2+1-npq=0,
$$

(quadratic equation on $q$):
$$
p\cdot q^2 + (p^2-np)q+1=0
$$

$$
q_{1,2}=\dfrac{np-p^2\pm\sqrt{p^4-2np^3+n^2p^2-4p}}{2p}.
$$

To be $q_{1,2}$ rational, must be

$$
p^4-2np^3+n^2p^2-4p = s^2, \qquad s\in \mathbb{Q}.
$$

If $p=\dfrac{a}{b}$, then $(x,y,z)=(2ab, 2b^2, abn-a^2\pm s)$ (after killing all common factors).

Of course, cyclic shift of $x,y,z$ may be applied here.

This way, we can find a few integer values of $n$ for not so large vlues of $x,y,z$ (see table below):

\begin{array}{|c|ll|}
\hline
n & (x,y,z) & \\ \hline
3 & (1,1,1) & \\ \hline
5 & (1,2,4) & \\ \hline 
6 & (4, 3, 18) & = (1\cdot 2^2, 3\cdot 1^2, 2\cdot 3^2) \\
  & (9, 2, 12) & = (1\cdot 3^2, 2\cdot 1^2, 3\cdot 2^2)\\ \hline
9 & (12, 63, 98) & =(3\cdot 2^2, 7\cdot 3^2, 2\cdot 7^2) \\
  & (18, 28, 147) &= (2\cdot 3^2, 7\cdot 2^2, 3\cdot 7^2) \\ \hline
10 & (175, 882, 1620) & = (7\cdot 5^2, 18 \cdot 7^2, 5\cdot 18^2 ) \\
   & (245, 450, 2268) & = (5\cdot 7^2, 18 \cdot 5^2, 7\cdot 18^2) \\ \hline
13 & (1053, 6422, 12996) & =(13\cdot 9^2, 38\cdot 13^2, 9\cdot 38^2)\\
   & (1521, 3078, 18772) & = (9\cdot 13^2, 38\cdot 9^2, 13\cdot38^2) \\ \hline
14 & (98, 52, 1183) & = (2\cdot 7^2, 13\cdot 2^2, 7\cdot 13^2)\\
   & (338, 28, 637) & = (2\cdot 13^2, 7\cdot 2^2, 13\cdot 7^2)\\ \hline
17 & (1620, 925, 24642) & = (5\cdot 18^2, 37\cdot 5^2, 18\cdot 37^2) \\
   & (6845, 450, 11988) & = (5\cdot 37^2, 18\cdot 5^2, 37\cdot 18^2)  \\ \hline
18 & (22932, 16055, 379050) \\
   & (117325, 7098, 167580) \\ \hline
19 & (25, 9, 405) \\
   & (81, 5, 225) \\ \hline
21 & (338, 84, 5733) \\
   & (882, 52, 3549) \\ \hline
26 & (12996, 7371, 314678) \\
   & (74529, 3078, 131404) \\ \hline
29 & (31347, 336518, 894348) \\
   & (49923, 132678, 1424332) \\ \hline
30 & (882, 124, 20181) \\
   & (1922, 84, 13671) \\ \hline
38 & (739900, 14341829, 27694870) \\
   & (1596070, 3082100, 59741791) \\ \hline
41 & (2, 36, 81) \\
   & (4, 9, 162) \\ 
   & (196, 5, 350) \\
   & (25, 14, 980) \\ 
   & (3698, 124, 41323) \\
   & (1922, 172, 57319) \\ \hline
51 & (1053, 13013, 53361) \\
   & (1521, 6237, 77077) \\ \hline
53 & (28, 1323, 1458) \\
   & (98, 108, 5103) \\ \hline
54 & (3698, 228, 139707) \\
   & (6498, 172, 105393) \\ \hline
57 & (1825900, 32851, 2567110) \\
   & (157339, 111910, 8745100) \\
66 & (3, 126, 196) \\
   & (9, 14, 588) \\ \hline
69 & (6498, 292, 303753) \\
   & (10658, 228, 237177) \\
   & (167580, 4720075, 11488218) \\
   & (379050, 922572, 25985255) \\ \hline
83 & (225, 4941, 18605) \\
   & (405, 1525, 33489) \\ \hline
86 & (10658, 364, 604513) \\
   & (16562, 292, 484939) \\ \hline
94 & (12229083, 132678, 22292452) \\
   & (894348, 490617, 82433078) \\ \hline
105 & (24642, 364, 919191) \\
    & (16562, 444, 1121211) \\ \hline
106 & (1225, 54, 102060) \\
  & (35, 66150, 2916) \\ \hline
... & ...
\end{array}

---

It iv **very interesting** that all founded values have form

$$
(x,y,z)_1 = (a^2b, b^2c, c^2a);\\
(x,y,z)_2 = (b^2a, a^2c, c^2b).
$$

Comment: Is this true that all solutions of this equation have the following form $$(x,y,z)_1 = (a^2b, b^2c, c^2a);\\
(x,y,z)_2 = (b^2a, a^2c, c^2b).$$?