# Solving $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} = m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{b} + \frac{b}{a }= n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Whether non-zero integers $a, b, c$ with the property that $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} = m \in \mathbb{Z}$$ and $$\frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{b} + \frac{b}{a }= n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ Calculate all possible values for $m + n$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: I can tell you that solving piece by piece seems to be a hard question. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848718/integer-values-of-fracxy-fracyz-fraczx

Comment: we can prove $|a|=|b|=|c|$

Answer (score 2):

We can assume that the three numbers do not a share a prime in their factorization. Rearrange the equations a bit:

$$a^2c + b^2a+c^2b = mabc \\
a^2b + c^2a + b^2c = nabc$$

Pick your favorite prime $p$. Suppose $N$ is largest so that $p^N\mid gcd(a,b)$.

If $p^{N+1}\nmid a$, then examine the second equation to see that $p^{2N}\mid a^2b,b^2c, nabc$ and so $p^{2N}\mid c^2a$, and so $p \mid c$.

If $p^{N+1}\nmid b$, then examine the first equation to see that $p^{2N}\mid a^2c,b^2a,mabc$ and so $p^{2N}\mid c^2b$, and so $p \mid c$.

This implies that a prime shared by 2 of the numbers is shared by the third, contradicting our initial assumption.

This is a hint to get you started. I'll add the rest of the solution later.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$\frac{a}{b}=x$ , $\frac{b}{c}=y$ , $\frac{c}{a}=z$

$x+y+z=m$, $xy+yz+zx=n$

$m+n+xyz+1=1+x+y+z+xy+yz+zx+xyz$

$m+n+2=(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)\geqslant 2^3\sqrt{xyz}=2^3$ AM-GM

$m+n+2\geqslant 8$

$m+n \geqslant 6 $

I'm not sure about my solution

Comment: I think there is a problem with using AM-GM here - that is that $x$, $y$, and $z$ may not be positive.

Comment: OK I'll wait for another solution

Comment: $(a,b,c) = (-1,1,1)$ gives $m + n = -2$, so things not being positive is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

let integer $a,b,c$ such $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}$ and $\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}$ is also integer, then we have
$$|a|=|b|=|c|$$

proof: WLOG:we may assume $gcd(a,b,c)=1$,Indeed,we can consider$\dfrac{a}{d},\dfrac{b}{d},\dfrac{c}{d}$
where $\gcd{(a,b,c)}=d$

a contradiction,then $a,b,c$ least one $\neq\pm 1$,WLOG $a\neq\pm 1$,and let prime number $p|a$,then
$$p|abc\left(\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\right)=a^2c+b^2a+c^2b$$
so
$p|c^2b$
so $p|b$ or $p|c$
WLOG: $p|b,p\nmid c$,and let $v_{p}(a)=r,v_{p}(b)=s,r\le s$,then we have
$$p^{r+s}|abc\left(\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}\right)=a^2b+c^2a+b^2c$$
But $$p^{s+r}\nmid c^2a,p^{r+s}\nmid b^2c,p^{r+s}|a^2b$$
a contradiction.

so
$$|a|=|b|=|c|$$
then easy to find $m,n$

Comment: I downvoted because this answer essentially finishes the partial answer I provided. I hoped the original poster would try to complete the problem themselves.