# Factoring Polynomials with four terms and three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $$\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{x} = 17,$$
>   then solve for $x$, $y$ and $z$, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are **positive integers**.

I got a common denominator of $xyz$, but then after that I was stuck:

$$x^2z + xy^2 + yz^2 = 17xyz$$

I also tried the quadratic formula, solving for $x$, but that was also a dead end:

$$x = \frac{-y^2+17zy \pm \sqrt{(y^2-17zy)^2-4z^3y}}{2z}.$$

I even wrote a rudimentary program to test a few numbers:

```
// index.js
function solve() {
    const limit = 10000;
    for (x = 1; x < limit; x++) {
        for (y = 1; y < limit; y++) {
            for (z = 1; z < limit; z++) {
                if (x*x*z + x*y*y + y*z*z === 17*x*y*z)
                    return { x, y, z };
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(solve());
```

Getting undefined. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $x=6845,y=450,z=11988$. If $x,y,z$ is a solution, then so is $nx,ny,nz$ so we need only consider cases where $x,y,z$ have no common factor. It is easy to show that if $p^n$ is highest power of prime $p$ dividing $x$, then $p^{2m}$ is highest power dividing $y$. Similarly, for other pairs, so we put $x=uw^2,y=u^2v,z=v^2w$ and then $u^3+v^3+w^3=17uvw$.

Comment: Related [Integer values of $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848718/integer-values-of-fracxy-fracyz-fraczx)

Comment: Damn. Thanks @almagest. I don't really understand the "it is easy to show that if ..." can you elaborate?

Comment: and how'd you get $2m$ from $n$?

Comment: And why bring power primes into this?